# end=' ' python syntax error

Tags: python-3.x

Have been to trying to learn python from a couple of days, encountered a syntax error but seems to work in the tutorial that I am learning from, here's the code

```
def func(a):
    for i in range(a,10):
        print(i,end=' ')
```

func(2)

And the error

```
print(i,end=' ')
           ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try `python --version`, are you positive that you are running at least version 3.0? I believe that syntax isn't permissible in earlier versions.

Comment: @eazar001 yes i am as the code works fine without the end=' '

Comment: appears in the eclipse preferences was set to v2.7,thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 this should work almost fine, however this will not work in Python 2 as it is a different syntax here is the code modified to work for different Python versions

## Python 3

```
def func(a):
    for i in range(a,10):
        print(i,end=' ')
>>> func(1)
>>> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

## Python 2

```
def func(a):
    for i in range(a,10):
        print i, # Trailing comma to signify not to start a new line

>>> func(1)
>>> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Additional detail

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#common-stumbling-blocks